# Keychain API in ObjectiveC, not C?

Tags: objective-c, keychain

I'm new to Cocoa and ObjectiveC and I'm writing a basic programme that uses a web service to login a user in to a website. I want to store the credentials in the Keychain and I've come across SecKeychainFindGenericPassword in the Keychain API. It's exactly what I need, but the example is written in C, not ObjectiveC!

I've tried invoking it like this: [SecKeychainFindGenericPassword .. and the autocomplete suggests all the parameters, but the types are const char *, not NSString*!

Can this function be used in ObjectiveC too? Can someone please show me a line of ObjectiveC that calls this function?

Thank you!

x

Comment: Obj-C is a superset of C, so anything written in C is also valid Obj-C.  My point being, you can freely intermix the two in .m files.

Answer (score 3):

Yes the function can be used but I would recommend using an existing [Objective-C keychain wrapper](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/GenericKeychain/Listings/Classes_KeychainItemWrapper_h.html). When you need a C string from an [`NSString`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) the easiest way is to use the `UTF8String` property.

```
const char *utf8str = [@"nsstring" UTF8String];
```

If you would like to specify a different encoding use `- (const char *)cStringUsingEncoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding`

For an example a quick google search brought up [this example](http://code.google.com/p/objectiveyoutube/source/browse/trunk/Demos/UploaderDemo/Keychain.m?r=2).

```
error = SecKeychainFindGenericPassword(keychain, strlen([service UTF8String]), [service UTF8String], strlen([account UTF8String]), [account UTF8String], &existingPasswordLength, (void **)&existingPasswordData, &existingItem);
```

Comment: Wow that was quick! Thanks Joe!

Comment: You are welcome I added a link to a keychain wrapper in Apple's example code. That would be easier then calling the native methods.